# Dual boot Debian & W10 bootloader?

Tags: debian, windows, grub2, dual-boot

So I want to make the move back to linux. I downloaded Debian cinnamon and made a bootable usb with Rufus. I am trying to get a dual boot set up for Windows and Debian. They both are installed on a different drive. But whenever I set Debian to boot first it does some checks on startup, clears screen and just keeps a blinking cursor/input dash without booting.

When installing I followed the steps but I see a lot of  different guides on how to do this, some mention that I should have GRUB after installation etc? I'm not sure. Also, I need to partition the Debian drive to GPT? Do I need to shrink a small size of that disk for grub as apposed to partitioning ?

Some of these questions might be silly, but I am really new to the 2 disc dual boot. In the past Ubuntu ran next to windows easily for me.

P.S If anyone has suggestions on a linux distribution suited for C#, JavaScript and HTML/CSS etc., let me know.

Comment: If Windows 10 from vendor, then it is UEFI/gpt as Microsoft has required vendors to use UEFI since Windows 8 released in 2012. So you want all drives a gpt and all installs as UEFI. I use Ubuntu. I think any Linux can do the things you asked about. Make sure installer is UEFI/gpt not CSM(UEFI) as CSM is BIOS emulation in UEFI.

Comment: The specification of gpt UEFI really makes it easier fo me to look around thanks. The only bit now is how do I handle the issue with it not booting and bootloader. I swear I did not see a single thing on grub when installing.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred I was kind of swamped in work stuff and almost forgot to reply. I was able to boot into Debian after reinstalling Grub. Which makes me think I just messed up the installation (not a experienced Linux/Debian user). Your replies did help me navigate it all a bit better.